# Postgresql turn null into zero

Tags: sql, postgresql, null, max

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SELECT max(x) is returning null; how can I make it return 0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688715/select-maxx-is-returning-null-how-can-i-make-it-return-0)

When I execute

```
select max(column) from mytable;
```

and my table has no rows, it returns null. How can I amend this select statement so it will return zero?

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
select coalesce(max(column), 0) from mytable;
```

Comment: Saving lifes even after 11 years, Thanks man

Answer (score 17):

Try:

```
SELECT coalesce(max(column), 0) myalias FROM mytable;
```

Answer (score 9):

Do either of these work?

- ```
  select coalesce(max(foo),0) from bar
  ```
- ```
  coalesce((select max(foo) from bar),0)
  ```