# When querying a table and joining a link table, Is it possible to check if a passed id is in join table and return as boolean in the result?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Sorry for the bad title, but I don't know how to describe what I'm trying to do, but hopefully my explanation will make sense.

Anyway, I have 3 tables in my database at the moment; `t_courses`, `t_users` and `t_enroll`. `t_enroll` is a join table between `t_courses` and `t_users`. The relationship looks like this:

[image: database relational view]

On this, I'm performing the following query:

```sql
SELECT t_courses.*, COUNT(t_enroll.iduser) AS 'enrolled' 
FROM t_courses 
LEFT JOIN t_enroll ON t_enroll.idcourse = t_courses.id 
WHERE t_courses.date >= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY t_enroll.idcourse
```

The idea here is to return all "upcoming" courses (the `WHERE t_courses.date >= CURRENT_DATE` part), with a count of the number of users enrolled on each of the courses.

This part works fine, however, the part I'm stuck trying to figure out is how I can make this query user specific.

What I mean, is that I would like to be able to find out if the user id specified as part of the query is enrolled on each course, and return it as a boolean (bit?).

Here is my current attempt to do this:

```sql
SELECT t_courses.*, COUNT(t_enroll.iduser) AS 'enrolled',
t_enroll.iduser = 50 as 'isUserEnrolled'
FROM t_courses 
LEFT JOIN t_enroll ON t_enroll.idcourse = t_courses.id 
WHERE t_courses.date >= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY t_enroll.idcourse
```

This doesn't work properly, as `isUserEnrolled` only returns true when the Id I pass happens to be the first user id related to that course in the join table. It feels like I need some kind of foreach loop, but I know that isn't a thing with SQL.

Does anyone have some ideas of what I could do to achieve the result I'm looking for?

**Edit** - Thanks to Popeye and his answer/comment, I was able to get a working query going, even fixing another issue I didn't realise my query had!

Here is the final SQL I've used:

```sql
SELECT t_courses.*, COUNT(t_enroll.iduser) AS 'enrolled',
IFNULL(MAX(CASE WHEN t_enroll.iduser = 55 then true end), 0) as 'isUserEnrolled'
FROM t_courses 
INNER JOIN t_enroll ON t_enroll.idcourse = t_courses.id 
AND t_courses.date >= CURRENT_DATE
GROUP BY t_enroll.idcourse
```

I've used `IFNULL` to return false (0) instead of NULL when the `MAX` does not find the user id in the join table. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688715/select-maxx-is-returning-null-how-can-i-make-it-return-0) is where I got the idea to use IFNULL (ISNULL for MSSQL).

Hope this helps someone if they stumble across this!

Comment: One suspects you're using a fairly ancient version of MySQL. It might be time to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query itself is not correct. It is actually `INNER JOIN` as you have used `where` clause on left joined table's colimn.

You should move `where` condition into `ON` clause as follows:

```
SELECT t_courses.*, COUNT(t_enroll.iduser) AS 'enrolled',
t_enroll.iduser = 50 as 'isUserEnrolled'
FROM t_courses 
LEFT JOIN t_enroll ON t_enroll.idcourse = t_courses.id 
And t_courses.date >= CURRENT_DATE -- used AND instead of WHERE
GROUP BY t_enroll.idcourse
```

Comment: I've moved the where clause to be part of the join statement, and changed the Left join to an inner join; the query is still working as it was before like this. However, I'm still having the same issue of `isUserEnrolled` only being true when the Id I pass happens to be the the first user Id joined to that course in the `t_enroll` table - any ideas for this part?

Comment: Use `max(case when t_enroll.iduser = 50 then true end)  as 'isUserEnrolled'`

Comment: Yep, that works well! Thank you, I'll accept your answer, and make an edit to my post to show the final SQL.