# Proper way to to handle null in getSingleResult aggregate

Tags: java, jpa, persistent

is there any proper way to handle null for example there is no existing record in the Users table, so it wont throw null pointer:

Comment: `.getSingleResult()` should be only used for queries when **single** result is guaranteed. Not multiple result, not empty result, but **single**. Perfect example - count queries (`select count(...)`), they never return null or multiple result

Comment: But the (Select MAX) is returning null.

Answer (score 2):

If the record does not exist in the database, do not use `getSingleResult()`. Looking at the javadoc, you need to be sure the record exists to use `getSingleResult()`

> **getSingleResult**
>
> java.lang.Object getSingleResult()
>
> Execute a SELECT query that returns a single untyped result.
>
> **Returns**:
> the result
>
> **Throws**:
>
> > `NoResultException` - if there is no result
> >
> > `NonUniqueResultException` - if more than one result

Instead, use [`getResultList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html#getResultList())

```java
public long generateNextId() {
    Query query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT MAX(id)+1 from Users");
    List<Object> objs = query.getResultList();
    return objs.isEmpty() ? 1 : Long.parseLong(objs.get(0));
}
```

Also, further, I'd use a `TypedQuery<Long>` if I were you

```java
public long generateNextId() {
    TypedQuery<Long> query = getEntityManager().createQuery("SELECT MAX(id)+1 from Users", Long.class);
    List<Long> objs = query.getResultList();
    return objs.isEmpty() ? 1 : objs.get(0);
}
```

---

If, like documented in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688715/select-maxx-is-returning-null-how-can-i-make-it-return-0), the query can return `null` then you can just use a `null` check or use an `Optional#ofNullable` wrapper

Comment: it seems query.getResultList() return size of 1 even there is no result in the query.

Comment: Can you print the content of the list?

Comment: its kinda weird since, its not looping. but the arraysize is = 1. maybe because of the SELECT MAX aggregate?

Comment: It is maybe because of the `+1`

Comment: I tried to remove. but its the same.. thats why its weird. I think the MAX is really returning null.

Comment: That is very surprising to be honest :D

Comment: confirmed. List<Long> objs  will have an element that is null. if  SELECT MAX returns null. for example the table is empty.

Comment: [Yes, that's true indeed @daniel.chan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1688715/select-maxx-is-returning-null-how-can-i-make-it-return-0)